# angular charts.js doughnut chart setting center text dynamically

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have created a doughnut chart with

```
public doughnutChartPlugins: PluginServiceGlobalRegistrationAndOptions[] = [{
    beforeDraw(chart:any) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const txt = 'Center Text';

      //Get options from the center object in options
      const sidePadding = 60;
      const sidePaddingCalculated = (sidePadding / 100) * (chart.innerRadius * 2)

      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      const centerX = ((chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2);
      const centerY = ((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2);

      //Get the width of the string and also the width of the element minus 10 to give it 5px side padding
      const stringWidth = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
      const elementWidth = (chart.innerRadius * 2) - sidePaddingCalculated;

      // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
      const widthRatio = elementWidth / stringWidth;
      const newFontSize = Math.floor(30 * widthRatio);
      const elementHeight = (chart.innerRadius * 2);

      // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
      const fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, elementHeight);

      ctx.font = fontSizeToUse + 'px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

      // Draw text in center
      ctx.fillText(txt, centerX, centerY);
    }
  }];
```

Currently, this works and show the value of txt in the middle of doughnut. However, I want the txt to be dynamic. The value is calculated on the click of a button based on some data from the service. I created a class level variable for this. But the trouble is using this.variable is not accessible inside the beforeDraw. how to access this variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a hacky solution. But this was the only way I could figure out to fix your issue. Hope it helps.
So, as per `ng2-charts` and `charts.js` documentation, an options object can be passed to the charts. And whatever values that are passed in this options object can be accessed in the `beforeDraw` method through the `chart` object. This can be used to achieve the behavior that you require.
Working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-doughnut-centertext-uu3ftp

In this sample, I pass a options object `chartOptions` to the chart.

```
public centerText: String = "Center Text";
public chartOptions: ChartOptions & { annotation: any } = {
  centerText: this.centerText
};
```

In the `beforeDraw` method, I access this value like below:

```
ctx.fillText(chart.options.centerText, centerX, centerY);
```

To modify this value, you need to set `chartOptions` to a new object:

```
this.chartOptions = {
  centerText: "Modified!!"
};
```

Please note that setting it like `this.chartOptions.centerText="Modified!!";` does not work. Also this will redraw the entire chart.

Comment: the problem with above is the error Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'centerText' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions & { annotation: any; }'. it goes away if you modify anything in ng2-chats.d.ts like adding a semi colon but this is not sufficient to be able to compile code

Comment: In stackblitz, this error was not being displayed. But when i created an example using angular cli, this error is there. I will try to fix it as well. I was trying to come up with a solution that does not redraw the entire chart. It almost worked but there was another issue. For evey second click, the fontsize of the center text becomes small.

Comment: well i dont need to modify text. all i need is to pass it dynamically

Comment: Please check this sample. It does not use the options object. It uses the animation event `onComplete` to draw the center text: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-doughnut-centertext-1kc2pg